# HTML Row headings on left

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a simple HTML table in which I want the first column values to act as heading for that row.Below is the link to the example

http://jsfiddle.net/eEEuv/

In the table,I want row1 and row2 as the heading and want to remove the left, top, and bottom borders around that column. I am able to remove the top border, but how to remove the left and bottom borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code and let me know if that works for you
http://jsfiddle.net/eEEuv/6/

Cheers

Comment: I came up with the same thing but you were quicker, so a plus one for you cuz i think this is right.

Answer (score 0):

style="border-left:0; border-bottom:0" in the main table tag

Comment: I want to remove the borders only for all the first columns.